# Query only works if I run a query before it

Tags: symfony, controller, doctrine

I want to get the schools the user is in, but for some reason I can only access it by running a query to the school table that is otherwise unrelated. Here is my code:

This doesn't work (within the controller):

```
$schoolsEnrolled = $this->getUser()->getSchools();
```

The result is an Array with a School object with all it's properties as null (other than id for some reason).

This does work (within the controller):

```
//unrelated query
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeMainBundle:School');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')->getQuery();
$schools = $query->getResult();

//the query I care about
$schoolsEnrolled = $this->getUser()->getSchools();
```

The result is an array of schools as desired.

### Here are the related methods:

In the School Class:

```
public function getSchools(){
    $schools = array();
    foreach ($this->schoolHasUsers as $key=>$schoolHasUser){
        $schools[] = $schoolHasUser->getSchool();
    }
    return $schools;
}
```

In the SchoolHasUser Class:

```
public function getSchool()
{
    return $this->school;
}
```

How can I get the query I care about to work without the unrelated query?

Comment: Maybe you don't need the unrelated query, but only activate the repository: `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeMainBundle:School');` ?

Comment: I tried without the query, but it doesn't work. I need the $schools = $query->getResult(); line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In doctrine object can be lazy-loaded. Then you call `$schoolHasUser->getSchool();` you trully no query the database, only get proxy object. So try to get some property of it, example getName or getId. This action make a call to DB and fetch object.

Comment: That worked! I changed the Method getSchools() in the User class to be $schools[] = $schoolHasUser->getSchool()->getName(); However, is there a way where I can get the entire object without having to explicitly get every property?

Comment: After you receive one property, you get entire object. You can var_dump it and see.

Answer (score 0):

One of the proper ways to do it is like this

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$entities = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity')->findAll();
```

Comment: I'm not trying to find all though, I want to find only the schools the user is associated with in the SchoolHasUser table.